# Simulate file with NLog (create virtual filesystem path)

Tags: c#, .net, nlog, logentries

I use NLog (with logentries.com) for logging in my WPF app, but some external components of my app accepts only filesystem path as log output. It is possible, to create "virtual path/file" which will be associated with NLog and every line appended to this "virtual file" will be routed directly to the Nlog (and then to logentries.com)?

Currently I'm using temporary file on disk, monitor changes of this file and resends updated content to the NLog, but it's not very effective.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a custom target for that. It's only a few lines!

```
[Target("MyFirst")] 
public sealed class MyFirstTarget: TargetWithLayout 
{ 
    public MyFirstTarget()
    {

    }

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent) 
    { 
       string logMessage = this.Layout.Render(logEvent); 

        // TODO - write me logMessage  to file
    } 

}
```

See a [news post related to this](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/30/extending-nlog-is-easy.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's a WP library we offer that can be used for sending log events to Logentries

[le-windows-phone](https://github.com/logentries-support/le-windows-phone)

Hope this helps!

Ardi
Logentries Support Engineer